# On iphone: how to show a new window transition from bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show a new window transition from bottom and transition to bottom when close,like the email App, when you write a new mail a new window transition from bottom, close this window the window transition to bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of `UIViewController`

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: and how to close this new window

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:

Answer (score 1):

Alex Deem is right. The UIModalTransitionStyle value is UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical. It is the default value and that is how a modal view will be presented using presentModalViewController:animated: method.

Comment: what are your options other than  UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical and how do you change that?

Comment: See the modalTransitionStyle property of a view in a view controller. That does the trick. And when you set it just type UIModalTrasitionStyle for the rvalue, XCode will autocomplete the other available options. UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal, UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve and UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl are the other 3 available. Else write your own view animation. Look up on CAAnimation & CATransition classes for that.